# Why is phar write support in PHP especially locked down?

Tags: php, security, phar

PHP has `phar.readonly` setting, which defaults to be enabled and can only be disabled via configuration file.

> This option disables creation or modification of Phar archives using the phar stream or Phar object's write support. This setting should always be enabled on production machines, as the phar extension's convenient write support could allow straightforward creation of a php-based virus when coupled with other common security vulnerabilities.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php

What is the reason for default block on write support in this context?

There are more generic and readily available ways to write in PHP, what exactly is "convenience" of Phar's write support which makes it dangerous from security point of view?

Comment: You can also disable it via CLI arg: `php -dphar.readonly=0 build-phar.php`

Comment: Note that if you just want to use Phar to create (non-executable) archives, you can still use [PharData](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) whatever the value of the `phar.readonly` setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write without readonly set then you can use ZIP or GZ container.  See [Head-to-head comparison of Phar, Tar and Zip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.comparison.php) for more info.

Having a PHAR readonly effectively locks it down from a hackers point of view.  If your Web version of PHP (mod_php, php-cgi or whatever) has the default, then this makes it very difficult to compromise a Phar based application as `phar.readonly=1` can be overridden during execution.

There is also a performance benefit in that the file is only opened R/O, and web requests -- which can be intrinsically concurrent -- can access and use the Phar without file locking.

You will typically build the Phar on your test configuration using a CLI wrapper as @scribu describes, and install it on your publicly accessible web service simply by copying the Phar to the relevant application directory.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question, which is - why phar writes are considered more exploitable and how is it enabling virus creation?

Comment: I did but implicitly.  If a PHP script contain a vulnerability which enables a hacker to compromise execution then she or he can take control and overwrite parts of the app to create a back door.  If your web facing PHP has `phar.readonly=1` then the hacker can't overwrite the application code.  Such writes throw an exception.  `ini_set()` doesn't work either as the execution can't lower the value below the PER_SYS value.